# How to retrieve the commit pointed to by a tag in LibGit2Sharp?

Tags: libgit2sharp

I initially thought this should be trivial, but how exactly can one get the commit to which a `Tag` object refers to in LibGit2Sharp?

Naively I thought we could get the sha by using `Tag.TargetIdentifier` but that points to the sha of the tag reference, not of the commit.

Then I thought that we could use `Tag.ResolveToDirectReference()` to peel away until we get to the commit, but this seems to return the same object.

The frustrating observation is that when inspecting the `Tag` object in the debugger there is a `Target` property which inside has another `Target` property that points to the commit, but I can't seem to access it anywhere in the API (even though it is not clearly marked as internal or private in the debugger).

There must be something really obvious I am missing but I couldn't find it from all the searches I've run.

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind, in the end it was trivial, but I had changed the way that I was reading in tags to use the `Refs` collection which returns a `Reference` object and not the `Tag` object where all the properties are indeed exposed.

The answer I was looking for with a proper `Tag` object is simply:

```cs
tag.Target == commit
```